# Qt nested QsqlQuery not working

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

I have the following problem:

I try to execute two nested queries but after I execute the secon query the results of the first query are deleted or whatever.

Example:
I have two items in the items table and two entries in the lendings table.
The first query holds these 2 items as a result but after the second query based on the first items is executed the sqlQuery.next() method does not deliver the second item anymore.

I hope it is understandable, sorry for that!

This is the method which loads items from the sqlite database:

```
ItemsList *DatabaseManager::getAllItems() {

this->db.open();

ItemsList* fetchedItems = new ItemsList();
QSqlQuery sqlQuery;

if (sqlQuery.exec("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE")) {
    while (sqlQuery.next()) {
        Item* fetchedItem = new Item();

        fetchedItem->setItemId(sqlQuery.value(0).toInt());
        fetchedItem->setName(sqlQuery.value(1).toString());
        addLendingsToItem(fetchedItem);

        ItemNode* fetchedItemNode = new ItemNode(fetchedItem);
        fetchedItems->add(fetchedItemNode);
    }
} else {
    qDebug() << sqlQuery.lastQuery();
    qDebug() << sqlQuery.lastError().text();
}
if (this->db.isOpen()) {
    this->db.close();
}
return fetchedItems; }
```

And this is the method which holds the second query:

```
void DatabaseManager::addLendingsToItem(Item* fetchedItem) {

QSqlQuery sqlQuery;
sqlQuery.prepare("SELECT i.itemId, i.name, l.lent, l.personId FROM items i JOIN lendings l ON i.itemId = l.itemId WHERE i.itemId = :itemId");               sqlQuery.bindValue(":itemId", fetchedItem->getItemId());
sqlQuery.bindValue(":itemId", fetchedItem->getItemId());

if (sqlQuery.exec()) {
    while (sqlQuery.next()) {
        if (sqlQuery.value(2).toInt() == 1) {
            fetchedItem->setPerson(getPerson(sqlQuery.value(3).toInt()));
            fetchedItem->setIsLent(true);
        } else {
            fetchedItem->getLentByList()->add(new PersonNode(getPerson(sqlQuery.value(3).toInt())));
        }
    }
} else {
    qDebug() << sqlQuery.lastQuery();
    qDebug() << sqlQuery.lastError().text();
} }
```

Comment: Try removing code from the inner function until it works.

Comment: Can you share the table structures and sample records? If you have a minimal version of the code you can share that exhibits the behaviour that would help diagnose what is happening (eg on bitbucket, github, or similar)

Some thoughts I had included:
* How many records does the outer query produce?

* Can you replace the pair of queries with a single select query?